# Combine [attribute=value] with :nth-child()

Tags: css, less, css-selectors

I'm using LESS and want to match an special input whose type is text.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
td {
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

For my second input of type checkbox, I need another width. I tried this:

```
td {
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100px;

        &:nth-child(2) {
             width: 40px;
        }
    }
}
```

But this won't work. Any ideas how to combine `[type=text]` with `:nth-child()`?

Comment: Don't have time to test with LESS, but a possible workaround would be to use `input[type=text]:nth-child(2)` instead of nesting. Then, if it still doesn't work, it's a bug with the selector. If it does, then it may be a bug in the LESS program you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your LESS should translate to the following CSS without any bugs:

```css
td input[type=text] {
    width: 100px;
}

td input[type=text]:nth-child(2) {
    width: 40px;
}
```

However, if you have other elements as siblings of your text inputs, these may be interfering with the `:nth-child()` declaration, as [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) only looks at an element's position relative to all its other siblings in the same parent, not only to other elements of its kind (i.e. `input[type=text]`). For example, if you had a `label` as the second child, then your input won't be the second child anymore as that spot has been taken by the label.

If the only inputs you have within your `td` are all of `[type=text]` you should be able to get away with using [`:nth-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) instead:

```
// LESS

td {
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100px;

        &:nth-of-type(2) {
             width: 40px;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

td input[type=text] {
    width: 100px;
}

td input[type=text]:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Just remember, though, that it only looks at the element name `input` and not the `[type=text]` attribute!

Or if you know you'll only have two text inputs you can use the general sibling selector instead to grab the one that *follows the first input*:

```
// LESS

td {
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100px;

        & ~ input[type=text] {
             width: 40px;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

td input[type=text] {
    width: 100px;
}

td input[type=text] ~ input[type=text] {
    width: 40px;
}
```